# Getting 500 on Google Cloud Storage endpoint

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to get my billing info of google project. I've enabled adding billing info and now I'm trying to get info from bucket(storage-123) by api:
[image]

Here I'm getting link for my csv file.I'm clicking in it and trying to do another request, but I'm getting 500 error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 JSON APIs for Google Cloud Storage. v1 (default), v1beta1 and v1beta2. You are using v1beta1 and when I use it, it gives me the same error.

On the other hand, using the API v1, I get the correct response (code 200). Try using Cloud Storage JSON API v1 not v1beta1.